# A posterior predictive check using R

Tags: r, self-study, bayesian, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian

Question:

On page 120,

[image]

the data from the SAT coaching experiments were checked against the
model that assumed identical effects in all eight schools: the expected order statistics
of the effect sizes were (26, 19, 14, 10, 6, 2, −3, −9), compared to observed data of (28,
18, 12, 8, 7, 1, −1, −3). Express this comparison formally as a posterior predictive
check comparing this model to the data. Does the model fit the aspect of the data
tested here?

My thinking:

Under the model that assumes identical effects in all eight schools (τ = 0), the posterior
distribution for the common θ is $N(7.7, 4.1^2)$; see page 119–120. To simulate the posterior predictive distribution of y rep we first simulate $θ ∼ N(7.7, 4.1^2)$ and then simulate y
rep j ∼ N(θ, σ_j^2) for j = 1, . . . , 8. The observed order statistics would be compared to the distribution of the order statistics obtained from the posterior predictive simulations. The expected order statistics provided in the problem (from a $N(8, 13^2)$ reference distribution) are approximately the mean order statistics we would find in the replications. (The mean in the replications would differ because the school standard errors vary and because the value 13 does not incorporate the variability in the common θ.). How can I show this graphically in R? I appreciate your suggestions!

This problem is from Gelman book exercise 6.1. Book link: [https://users.aalto.fi/~ave/BDA3.pdf](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Eave/BDA3.pdf)

Comment: Can you clarify what book this is from? You mention page numbers multiple times, but it's not clear which book (or edition) this comes from

Comment: @Billy This is exercise 6.1 from Gelman book. https://users.aalto.fi/~ave/BDA3.pdf

Comment: I thought so but wanted to check. Appendix C, starting on page 591, uses the 8-schools data to show how to fit a hierarchical model in R, and that same Appendix includes how to do the posterior predictive checks

Comment: @Billy I wanted to avoid using stan. I was looking for alternative way as they did in the R demo. Here is the link: https://avehtari.github.io/BDA_R_demos/demos_ch6/demo6_1.html

Comment: Then you need to know the posterior distribution, which means that you need to use conjugate priors to ensure your posterior has a known distributional shape. This is what is done in the linked post from Vehtari: the posterior distribution for a population mean with unknown variance is a t-distribution (see pp. 64-66 for proof and conjugate priors needed for this to hold). For the hierarchical model, how to sample from the posterior predictive distribution as done in the link you just provided is reviewed on pages 113-119